# VSTO Excel template are not loaded when other EXCEL files are open

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

There is a problem. I have the vsto Excel template (c#). This one works perfectly, but if with it works other file excel then happens something mysterious. After exit from add-in i can`t enter to it again until i`ll close other Excel files. I thought that it was depended on wrong way to exit from add-in, but i tryed the following ways which didn`t decide my problem:

```
  private void ThisWorkbook_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Quit();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have created a document-level customization. This means you will see your buttons/code running just for the **one** workbook.
If you really wants to have your Ribbon available just for some types of your workbooks then create a **workbook template** `xltx`. (*not xlsx, xlsb or xlsm*)
All workbooks created from your template will have your custom functionality. Please check this guide from Microsoft - [Get started programming document-level customizations for Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/getting-started-programming-document-level-customizations-for-excel?view=vs-2017)

The concept is like this.

1. You create a VSTO Template customization in Visual Studio
2. Make your Ribbon, write your code and build your project
3. In your **Release** folder you will get your Excel template, like `ExcelTemplate.xltx`
4. Distribute this file to your clients
5. Every time someone creates a new workbook from your template, it will have your customization but standard Excel files will not

To be honest with you I think that over years I've created just one project like this (usually I do VSTO add-ins). I don't know how you will manage updates/bug-fixes while you or your clients may already create thousands of files based on one version of your template => think in advance to have some update logic/versioning system. 
I seem to remember that the one project I did, had some issue with running the code on non developer machine. I'd say I had to manually tweak registry to get it running but it may change it was really 5-6 years ago (*maybe even more*)

You can also consider the VSTO add-in and set the visibility (*Ribbon callbacks*) of your Ribbon based on some document property etc. So you will have your add-in that will load every time Excel loads but based on some internal checks it will make the Ribbon visible or hidden.

> ```
>     private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
>     {
>         Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.WorkbookOpen += Application_WorkbookOpen;
>         Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.WorkbookActivate += Application_WorkbookActivate;
>     }
>
>     private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
>     {
>         Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.WorkbookOpen -= Application_WorkbookOpen;
>         Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.WorkbookActivate -= Application_WorkbookActivate;
>     }
>
>     private void Application_WorkbookActivate(Excel.Workbook Wb)
>     {
>         var passThisValueToRibbonCallback = IsSupportedDocument(Wb);
>     }
>
>     private void Application_WorkbookOpen(Excel.Workbook Wb)
>     {
>         var passThisValueToRibbonCallback = IsSupportedDocument(Wb);
>     }
>
>     /// <summary>
>     /// An example how to check if opened/activated document is 'your' document
>     /// </summary>
>     /// <param name="workbook"></param>
>     /// <returns></returns>
>     private bool IsSupportedDocument(Excel.Workbook workbook)
>     {
>         var props = workbook.CustomDocumentProperties;
>         try
>         {                
>             var myCustomProperty = props.Item["myPropertyThatWillBeJustInMyWorkbooks"];
>             return true;
>         }
>         catch (Exception)
>         {
>             return false;
>         }
>     }
> ```

Please also check this [Features available by Office application and project type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/features-available-by-office-application-and-project-type?view=vs-2017)

Comment: if i understand it right, for using Ribbon panel i`ll have to make VSTO Add-ins (not Document-level customizations)? But in this case my Ribbon panel will be started in every Excel document. What if i want to see my panel only in the certain document?

Comment: @Andrey I edited my answer based on your comment, hope that helps

Comment: PetLahev - thanks a lot for your explanation. It is very useful for me. I`ll try to redo my project according to your recommendations.